# Accessing files on a macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, filevault, login

My boyfriend died in a violent hit and run.

All of his photos are on his macbook pro laptop. His iphone is locked with a pin code and his computer is locked with a password or a recovery key. His mobile has been disconnected by the phone company already. I have a death certificate.

I am able to access his icloud account and his ipad, but I don't have his computer password or the recovery key. The computer was protected by filevault.

Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: Can the MacBook password be reset using iCloud password ? This is something an user has to choose when setting up FileVault. If not, then you'd have to locate the recovery key.

Comment: Do you know his *actual* iCloud password?  If so, you can reset a password using his AppleID.  see:  https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202860